# Is it possible to display multiple tasks on a single line using ProjectLibre?

Tags: tasks, gantt, meetings, timeline, projectlibre

I have a project that I have 15 main tasks on. One of them is `Meetings`. I have had `X` meetings, and the duration is `1-day`. Is there any way to show multiple bars on a single line showing these Meetings as square bars? (something similar that the [Office Timeline add-in](https://www.officetimeline.com/) shows/creates in Power Point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unfortunately ProjectLibre doesn't support recurring tasks

Welcome to pm.stackexchange!

> Is there any way to show multiple bars on a single line showing these
> Meetings as square bars?

In order to show multiple bars on a single line, you need to be able to create recurring tasks. Unfortunately ProjectLibre doesn't have the capability to designate a task as 'recurring'. So, the answer is, no you can't do that.

You can check the documentation here - [ProjectLibre User Guide v1.3.0 Aug 2020](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RC1s_1GVzLd_T2M3NJrJo3ATIBIheWE_c8nWHJffm3Y/edit#).

Comment: Thank you. Would you know if MSO Visio supports this? If so, which versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can split a task by right clicking and selecting split.  If you combine this with displaying as a milestone you can place diamonds where each meeting is required.